# Create a stream file from online radio stream URL

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, url, internet-radio

I have an URL from an online radio stream. I use it in VLC to listen to it. However every time i want to listen to it I need to manually input it in the "Media -> Open Network Stream...".
I want to make a single file that I could double click and auto-play it so I wouldn't have to manually enter it. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple shortcut to VLC with a parameter being the URL you want to open will do the trick.

For example:

1. Right-click desktop
2. Click New
3. Click Shortcut
4. Paste "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "http://mp3uplink.duplexfx.com:8700" into the location box with the inverted commas.  Just an example.  You might need to change the path to VLC on your computer and you will of course need to change the URL/port to whatever you want to open.

Simply double-click your shortcut to open the stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an M3U file with your stream URL. Then you just open that file and your default media player will play it. For example, here is the content of an M3U file for Neringa FM radio stream.

**neringafm.m3u**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,Neringa FM Stream
http://radio.15min.lt:8000/neringafm
```